# Событие нажатия объекта button (actionscript 3)

Tags: flash

Есть 2 формы и кнопка. Как прописать евент активации кнопки (не только нажатием мыши, но и любым другим способом, например фокус + нажатие пробела.

```
this.butonConfirm.addEventListener(event, function);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем как слушать клавиши с объекта, нужно установить на него фокус приложения.

```
MainDisplayObject.stage.focus = this.butonConfirm;
this.butonConfirm.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler);
```